# I want to make similar react hook same as useFormik or useMutation provided by apollo/client, in where I can run onSuccess or onError functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-custom-hooks

I've made a custom react hook called `useAxiosPost` which makes a post request to an endpoint. But I also want to perform some action to the data returned by the `API`. I want to pass a object as a parameter which already has a function (recommended by typescript). And in the argument of that function, there is already data returned by API.

My current setup is:

Custom hook:

```
// useAxiosPost.ts
function useAxiosPost({ onSuccess }: UseAxiosPostOptions): [
```

And in other file where I have to use it:

```
 const {...} = useAxiosPost({
      onSuccess(data) {
        // This data is returned by API
        // Do something with this data.
        console.log(data) 
      },
    });
```

I want to call `onSuccess(data)` or `onError(error)` function inside the arguments for the hook itself.

This is somehow similar with `useMutation()` hook provided by `@apollo/client` or the `useFormik()` hook provided by Formik.

Example of hook provided by formik :

```
const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      username: "",
      email: "",
      password: "",
    },
    async onSubmit(values, formikError) {
      // Do something with the values
      console.log(values);
```

How can I setup something similar in the hook?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution myself after asking the same question to ChatGPT.
On the hook itself accept two functions as props:

```
interface UseAxiosPostOptions {
  onSuccess?: (data: any) => void;
  onError?: (error: any) => void;
}
function useAxiosPost({ onSuccess, onError }: UseAxiosPostOptions): [
```

And inside the function somewhere, call the function itself (the function is optional we have to call optionally):

```
try {
      const axiosData = await axios.post(`http://localhost:8000/${url}`, data, {
        withCredentials,
      });
      onSuccess?.(axiosData.data);
```

And in the place where we want to use the hook simply do the following:

```
const {...} = useAxiosPost({
      onSuccess(data) {
        console.log("DATA FOUND");
        console.log(data); // This data is returned by API
      },
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy